# applescript title nowrap?

Tags: user-interface, macos, applescript

Is it possible to set a "nowrap" on a title of a display box?

for example:

```
set selectedSite to (choose from list MySites with prompt "Which site would you like to use:" with title AppTitle without multiple selections allowed)
```

Since the sites listed in that box are rather small, the title of the box wraps, is there a way to prevent the wrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the regular spaces in the prompt string with non-breaking spaces by typing Option-Space instead of just Space, but that only shifts the point where it wraps, as it still can't fit—it doesn't resize the window to fit it. I'd suggest changing the prompt string to be shorter instead.